# Extract emails in brackets

Tags: r, extract, powerquery, gmailr

I work with gmailR and I need to extract emails from brackets <> (sometimes few in one row) but in case when there are no brackets (e.g. `name@mail.com`) I need to keep those elements.

This is an example

```r
x2 <- c("John Smith <jsmith@company.ch>  <abrown@company.ch>","no-reply@cdon.com" ,
        "<rikke.hc@hotmail.com>")
```

I need output like:

```
[1] "jsmith@company.ch"       "abrown@company.ch"
[2] "no-reply@cdon.com"
[3] "rikke.hc@hotmail.com"
```

I tried this in purpose to merge that 2 results

```r
library("qdapRegex")
y1 <- ex_between(x2, "<", ">", extract = FALSE)
y2 <- rm_between(x2, "<", ">", extract = TRUE )
```

My data code sample:

```r
from <- sapply(msgs_meta, gm_from)
from[sapply(from, is.null)] <- NA
from1 <- rm_bracket(from)
from2 <- ex_bracket(from)

gmail_DK <- gmail_DK %>% 
  mutate(from = unlist(y1)) %>%
  mutate(from = unlist(y2))
```

but when I use this function to my data (only one day emails) and unlist I get

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `cc = unlist(cc2)`.
> x `cc` must be size 103 or 1, not 104.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I suppose that in data from more days difference should be bigger, so I prefer to not go this way.

Preferred answer in R but if you know how to make it in for example PowerQuery should be great too.

Answer (score 2):

We may also use `base R` - split the strings at the space that follows the `>` (`strsplit`) and then capture the substring between the `<` and `>` in `sub` (in the replacement, we specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group) - `[^>]+` - implies one or more characters that are not a `>`

```
sub(".*<([^>]+)>", "\\1", unlist(strsplit(x2, 
       "(?<=>)\\s+", perl = TRUE)))
[1] "jsmith@company.ch"    "abrown@company.ch"  
[3]  "no-reply@cdon.com"    "rikke.hc@hotmail.com"
```

Comment: It work well with "from", but with "to" and "cc" when can be multiple emails, then it didn't work with more that 2 values in cc or from. For example `[1] "Company Danmark <mail@company.dk>, Booking <booking@faircargonow.com>, Smith- Fair Cargo Now <smith@faircargonow.com>, John Surname <mail+john@company.dk>` " It return only last value 'mail+john@company.dk'

Comment: If you have other test cases, you need to show them to us (edit your question to include them)

Answer (score 1):

Clunky but OK?

```r
(x2 
   ## split into single words/tokens
   %>% strsplit(" ")
   %>% unlist()
   ## find e-mail-like strings, with or without brackets
   %>% stringr::str_extract("<?[\\w-.]+@[\\w-.]+>?") 
   ## drop elements with no e-mail component
   %>% na.omit()   
   ## strip brackets
   %>% stringr::str_remove_all("[<>]")
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what all of the legal elements in an e-mail string are: it's possible that `[^@]+` would be better for capturing the components before and after the `@` ...

Comment: Sorry, Im total newby in regex. You mean stringr::str_extract("<?[\\w-.][^@]+@[^@][\\w-.]+>?")? If yes, in my case it work same.

Comment: U function work well with "from", but with "to" and "cc" when values can be null then are some problems from na.omit()